# How can I read with the Autodesk Forge api the value of the model field of an asset in the Build/asset module?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Neither the get asset api nor the relationship api shows the value. The only way I see the asset is set when you use the add a 3 d model in the asset module and import the objects.

I did use the api   [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/assets/v2/projects/{{project_id}}/assets](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/assets/v2/projects/%7B%7Bproject_id%7D%7D/assets)?  and  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/relationship/v2/ but none of the responses showed the model field or entity id of the linked model

Answer (score 0):

It requires additional API to get related data for Assets Model-based workflow. However, unfortunately, there is no API available for Assets Model-based workflow at this moment. Please stay tuned with us.